# Definition of \strut explained

Tags: tex-core, boxes, strut

Can anyone explain me the fine details of the `\strut` macro. Why is the box `\copy`ied in mathmode but `\unhcopy`ied otherwise?

```
% latex.ltx, line 484, but identical in plainTeX
\def\strut{\relax\ifmmode\copy\strutbox\else\unhcopy\strutbox\fi}
```

*The TeXBook* states (e.g. page 120) that the unboxing macros unset any glue in the box's outer level, but there is no glue in the `\strutbox`, is it?

I understand that `\strutbox` is an actually empty box with a font size dependent height (`.7\baselineskip`, where `\baselineskip` is about 1.2x font size) and depth (`.3\baselineskip`) but zero width:

```
% latex.ltx, line 2357, inside the `\set@fontsize` macro
\setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
  \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
        \@depth.3\baselineskip
        \@width\z@}%
```

I assume it is more efficient to use a box instead of repeatably use `\vrule`. Also you can use `\ht\strutbox` and `\dp\strutbox` to access the height and depth as dimensions. This allows you to write `.5\ht\strutbox` while `.5*.7\baselineskip` would require eTeX's `\dimexpr` or a temporal assignment.

I really like to understand the fine nuances of TeX better.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't `\unhcopy` an hbox in math mode, that's simple! Indeed

```
$\unhcopy\strutbox$
```

gives

```
! Incompatible list can't be unboxed.
<*> $\unhcopy\strutbox
                      $
```

The command `\unhcopy` is used outside of math mode because of two facts:

1. it starts horizontal mode;
2. it removes one level of boxing, avoiding "too deep" nesting.

A similar definition is that of `\leavevmode`:

```
\def\leavevmode{\unhbox\voidb@x}
```

where `\voidb@x` is a box register that should always remain void. The difference between `\unhbox` and `\unhcopy` is that the former destroys the contents of the box register, while the latter produces only a copy of it and leaves the register intact.

Among the duties of `\fontsize` is to provide a convenient `\strut`; the strut's height and depth are always 7/10 and 3/10 of the baselineskip, which is set by the second argument to `\fontsize`. So when a command such as `\large` is executed, also the strut is changed; it will restored when the group ends or another `\fontsize` command (possibly implicit) is executed.

(For the rest you're right.)

### Note.

The register `\voidb@x` can be used to ensure that a box register is void, by saying `\setbox\mybox=\box\voidb@x`, which destroys the contents of `\mybox` and is more efficient than the equivalent `{\setbox0=\box\mybox}`.

Comment: I see, both things make perfect sense: Unboxing a non-math hbox in mathmode wouldn't be right and removing one unnecessary boxing level is of course more efficient. Nice answer! (As usual, I'm waiting a little bit before accepting it)