# how to remove additional space around \underbrace and justify the text under it

Tags: math-mode, spacing, braces

How do I

1. remove the additional space around \underbrace
2. justify the text under it, if the latter is longer than the text above it?

To illustrate the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\underbracewithoutspace}[2]{\mathrlap{\underbrace{\phantom{#1\strut}}_{#2}}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\underbrace{a+b}_{\text{a long blah blah blah}}+c
\end{equation}

% using the technique of 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24912/remove-additional-space-around-underbrace  
\begin{equation}
\underbracewithoutspace{a+b}{\text{a long blah blah blah}}+c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The first line (plain `\underbrace`) tries to center the text under the brace, while the second version (taken from this question: [Remove additional space around \underbrace{…}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24912/remove-additional-space-around-underbrace)) puts the brace under the wrong symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\undertab}[1]{\clap{%
  \scriptsize\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}

\underbracewithoutspace{a+b}{\undertab{a long\\ blah\\ blah}}+c
```

I wouldn't look for justification in such narrow columns.

Comment: Thanks! What I'm after is not justification _per se_, it's correct positioning of the text/formula under the brace if it's longer than what's above it.

As a more minor issue: is there a way of aligning what's above the brace with what's below it? In this example, I'm after aligning the `a` in the 'a long ' with the `a` in the formula.