# How to remove an unwanted white space at the last end of a horizontal curly brace?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, amsmath

You can see there is an unwanted white space at the last term below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$
\lefteqn{\textstyle\overbrace{\phantom{1+2+3+4}}^{\alpha}}1+2+
    \underbrace{3+4+
        \lefteqn{\textstyle\overbrace{\phantom{5+6+7}}^{\beta}}5+6}_{\gamma}+7
$
\end{document}
```

What causes the white space? And how to remove it?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24912/21591 help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The boxing interferes with the math spacing, if you make the phantoms visible you see what is being braced:

If you correct for the mathop spacing you can make them align exactly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,color}
\begin{document}
$
\lefteqn{\textstyle\overbrace{\phantom{1+2+3+4}}^{\alpha}}1+2+
    \underbrace{3+4+
        \lefteqn{\textstyle\overbrace{\phantom{5+6+7}}^{\beta}}5+6}_{\gamma}+7
$


\def\xphantom#1{\hbox{{\color{red}$#1$}}}
$
\lefteqn{\textstyle\overbrace{\xphantom{1+2+3+4}}^{\alpha}}1+2+
    \underbrace{3+4+
        \lefteqn{\textstyle\overbrace{\xphantom{5+6+7}}^{\beta}}5+6}_{\gamma}+7
$

$\setbox0\hbox{$3+4$}
\overbrace{1+2+3+4}^{\alpha}
\kern-\wd0\!
\underbrace{3+4+5+6}_{\gamma}
\kern-\wd0\!
\overbrace{5+6+7}^{\beta}
$
\end{document}
```

See the discussion in

[How to fix the math-spacing when a lot of \phantom, \mathrlap, etc. are used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95897/how-to-fix-the-math-spacing-when-a-lot-of-phantom-mathrlap-etc-are-used)

Answer (score 5):

I've just released a new package designed to solve just this problem! It is called [`underoverlap`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/underoverlap).

Here's how I would then set your example:

```
$
    \UOLoverbrace{1+2+}[3+4]^\alpha \UOLunderbrace{+}[5+6]_\gamma \UOLoverbrace{+7}^\beta
$
```

[image]

It needs no duplication in your source code and spacing is automatically correct in most cases (mostly thanks to David's help in the question he links to in his answer.)

Comment: Have you registered this to ["Problems lead to package creations"](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1722/19356)?