# Defining variants of \small and \large that use \normalsize's line spacing

Tags: macros, fontsize, line-spacing, starred-version, grid-typesetting

As a partial workaround for grid typesetting, I'd like to define variants of `\small` and `\large` that behave like their standard counterparts except that they use the line spacing of `\normalsize`. I know that I can look up the respective macro definitions for, e.g., the `10pt` standard class option in `size10.clo` and accordingly define the new variants, e.g.,

```
\newcommand\largeVAR{\@setfontsize\largeVAR\@xiipt\@xiipt}
```

However, I'm looking for an automatic solution that works for all (possibly custom) `.clo` option files, i.e., one that dynamically adapts to the respective standard macro definitions.

Bonus points for a solution showing how to add starred macro versions (`\small*`, `\large*`).

Comment: The solution to the grid problem, is hidden in the `multicols` package. Whatever you do it always balances the grid, even with oddly sized figures. Floats are the major culprits for breaking a grid. A better approach would be to redefine headers etc, to be in multiples of the baseline skip.

Comment: sorry not true. `multicols` doesn't do grids. All it does is trying to ensure that baselines at top and bottom of the columns agree. But depending on the spacing inside the column there may not be alignment elsewhere and definitely no alignment from page to page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\@standardbaselineskip{\the\baselineskip}}
\let\@@small\small
\def\small{\@ifstar\s@small\@@small}
\def\s@small{\@@small\fontsize{\f@size}{\@standardbaselineskip}\selectfont}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
{\small\lipsum[2]}
{\small*\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It *may* work also for `\large`, but there's `\lineskip` to be taken into account. It definitely won't work for larger sizes than `\large`.

For `\large` the modification is similar:

```
\let\@@large\large
\def\large{\@ifstar\s@large\@@large}
\def\s@large{\@@large\fontsize{\f@size}{\@standardbaselineskip}\selectfont}
```

From my experiments, the baseline skip is uniform even between lines with descenders and lines with ascenders, with Computer Modern fonts. With other fonts it's not sure *a priori*. However I refuse to show the result, which is horrible. :)

Comment: +1 for pointing me to `\f@size`. Am I right that this solution assumes (perhaps according to standard LaTeX convention) that `\normalsize` is in effect at the begin of the document body?

Comment: `\normalsize` is issued by `\document`, but before expanding the `\AtBeginDocument` tokens. That's why I put the definition of `\@standardbaselineskip` there. If this code comes after package loading, it should be safe.

Comment: Re: horrible result: `\large*` is intendend for sectioning headings not exceeding one line.

Comment: @lockstep I heartfully hoped so. :)

Comment: @egreg I don't see any advantages in simply doing `\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{\the\baselineskip}}`, am I missing something?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides lockstep asked for a *-variant

Comment: @egreg -- Sorry, I see your reasoning.