# Multiplying a length by a factor

Tags: vertical-alignment, line-spacing, calculations, lengths

I am trying to create a package that will use grid typesetting (in the humanities, so not much of a problem) but that should allow the user to freely set the `\baselinestretch`. I am using the `memoir` class as a basis.

In order to do so, I have defined some font sizes, and calculated the amount of space which I should add, for instance after a `\Large` heading, so as to preserve the vertical alignment; then I am setting the lengths accordingly. So, for instance:

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}\selectfont
\renewcommand*{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12}{14.5}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*{\Large}{\fontsize{17}{22}\selectfont}
\def\addto@Large{7.7pt}

\setlength{\beforechapskip}{\addto@Large}
\addtolength{\beforechapskip}{\baselineskip}
```

It works so far, but I would like to be able to change `\baselinestretch` at will. In order to do that, I basically need to define my `\addto@Large` command for a stretch factor of one (so that would be `7pt` here), and then multiply it by the `\baselinestretch` factor.

Is it possible, and if so, how can I do that?

Comment: It is not really clear for me but to calculate length you can use `dimexpr` or `glueexpr` provide by e-TeX.

Comment: The `\addto@Large` length seems to assume single-line headings. So, why not define a variant of `\Large` with "normalsized" line spacing (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38613/defining-variants-of-small-and-large-that-use-normalsizes-line-spacing) and add multiples of `\baselineskip` before and after headings?

Comment: @lockstep Yes, I have seen this question and implemented the answer on some of the lengths I commonly use (for footnotes, e.g.), but thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several choices. For example define `\addto@Large` as a dimen parameter:

```
 \newdimen\addto@Large
 \addto@Large=7pt

 \setlength{\beforechapskip}{\baselinestretch\addto@Large}
 \addtolength{\beforechapskip}{\baselinestretch\baselineskip}
```

You can also do in one swoop, by using `\dimexpr`:

```
 \setlength\beforechapskip{\baselinestretch\dimexpr\addto@Large+\baselineskip\relax}
```

In this case `\addto@Large` can also be defined as you did; but it's best to have it as a dimen parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works as described generally speaking, but it seems to break the vertical alignment by a small amount – both solutions seem to alter it, though differently. EDIT — My mistake, the problem comes from my code (probably). I got it to work eventually.