# Can I assume that the \ht+\dp of a strutbox == \baselineskip?

Tags: spacing, best-practices, plain-tex, strut

In Context, as long as the interline space is set through the
proper interface, it is safe to assume that `(tex.box.strutbox.height
+ tex.box.strutbox.depth) == tex.baselineskip.width`. This relation
is important when copying the strutbox to add empty lines to
some vlist.

However, I am working in *Plain* at the moment, where there is
no such interface. Knuth in his examples sets the baseline skip
independently of the strutbox, and what is more he uses absolute
point values. Also, he defines multiple strutboxes *with different
height/depth ratios* in `gkpmac.tex` and elsewhere. Yet, in
`manmac.tex` (and Appendix E, p. 414f.) the bodyfont switches
(`\tenpoint`, `\ninepoint` etc.) include appropriate strutboxes
whose `\ht` + `\dp` equal the `\baselineskip`. Unfortunately
I don’t have the experience that I could tell whether this is a
convention amongst Plain users or just, well, Knuth.

So my questions: Is it reasonably safe to assume that whoever
defines a font switch for Plain TeX will also take care of the
strutbox? If I encounter a strutbox whose sum of height and
depth does not match the local baselineskip, is it safe to
recalculate these dimensions and overwrite the current strutbox?
Is there some convention as to what is the correct height/depth
ratio? Is it possibly part of the font metadata (OTF)? (Bonus
points for good links: I can’t seem to google the
topic without having my results cluttered with source files.)

For reference some code to recreate the strutbox in case its
dimensions don’t match the baselineskip.

```
local strutbox = texbox.strutbox
local get_strut = function ()
  local strutht, strutdp = strutbox.height, strutbox.depth
  local struthtdp        = strutht + strutdp
  local texbaselineskip  = tex.baselineskip.width
  local newstrut         = node.copy_list(tex.box.strutbox)
  strutht = (strutht / struthtdp) * texbaselineskip
  strutdp = (strutdp / struthtdp) * texbaselineskip
  newstrut.height, newstrut.list.height = strutht, strutht
  newstrut.depth,  newstrut.list.depth  = strutdp, strutdp
  return newstrut
end
local my_strut = get_strut()
print(string.format("strutbox ht %.4f, dp %.4f, htdp %.2f factor %.2f",
                    strutbox.height / 2^16,
                    strutbox.depth  / 2^16,
                    (strutbox.height + strutbox.depth) / 2^16,
                    (strutbox.height / strutbox.depth)))
print(string.format("my_strut ht %.4f, dp %.4f, htdp %.2f factor %.2f",
                    my_strut.height / 2^16,
                    my_strut.depth  / 2^16,
                    (my_strut.height + my_strut.depth) / 2^16,
                    (my_strut.height / my_strut.depth)))
print(strutbox)
print(strutbox.list.height/2^16)
tex.box.strutbox = my_strut
```

(Similar topic but afaics the specified ht/dp ratio doesn’t hold
for plain  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21834/14066)

Comment: many plain users will follow knuth's convention for the height and depth of a strut as in `manmac`.  (this is true for ams-tex, for example.)  but i wouldn't want to guarantee that the practice is universal.  (note that `\mathstrut` is different -- it has only the height and depth of a parenthesis in the current font, and shouldn't be larger.)  regarding font metadata in otf, my guess is that it depends on the whim of whoever designed the font.

Comment: This is true for LaTeX, since every font size change command recomputes the strut box. With `ofs.tex` for Plain the strut is not taken into consideration; other font managers operate at even lower level.

Comment: @egreg I just hat a look at one of the font managers, [plnfss](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/plain/plnfss/tex/plain/plnfss/plnfss.tex). It provides a macro ``\setbaselineskip`` that also resets the strutbox according to the 7:3 height/depth proportion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

many plain users will follow knuth's convention for the height and depth of a strut as in `manmac.tex`.  there he defines three base sizes, each with its own value for `\strutbox`:

```
\def\tenpoint{\def\rm{\fam0\tenrm}%
  <...>
  \normalbaselineskip=12pt
  <...>
  \setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height8.5pt depth3.5pt width\z@}%
  \normalbaselines\rm}

\def\ninepoint{\def\rm{\fam0\ninerm}%
  <...>
  \normalbaselineskip=11pt
  <...>
  \setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height8pt depth3pt width\z@}%
  \normalbaselines\rm}

\def\eightpoint{\def\rm{\fam0\eightrm}%
  <...>
  \normalbaselineskip=9pt
  <...>
  \setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height7pt depth2pt width\z@}%
  \normalbaselines\rm}
```

as one can see, the height + depth of the `\strutbox` *does* equal the `\normalbaselineskip`, with the height and depth greater than the cap height and descender depth relatively in proportion; not all the "excess" is above or below.
(other plain formats follow this principle; `ams-tex` does, for example.)  but i wouldn't want to guarantee that the practice is universal.

note that `\mathstrut` is different -- it is defined in `plain.tex`:

```
\def\mathstrut{\vphantom(}
```

so it has only the height and depth of a parenthesis in the current font, and shouldn't be larger.  (this can be a trap with fonts not designed for use with math; tex fonts have vertically symmetrical parentheses, with equal extents above and below the math axis.  fonts designed with only text setting in mind may not have a well defined math axis at all, so "your mileage may vary".  check!  then, if necessary, define the `\mathstrut` as a `\vphantom` of two characters, one having the maximum height found in the set comprising alphabet + numerals + punctuation, and the other having the maximum depth.)

as designer of numerous document-specific plain styles, including that of *tugboat*, i faithfully adhere to the `manmac` principle; it ensures uniformity without effort, so attention need be paid only to exceptional situations.

`gkpmac.tex` *is* an exceptional case.  it was designed for one particular book, *Concrete Mathematics*, which did not have varying blocks of *main* text in different sizes.  instead, it had well-controlled "inserts" (which for this discussion include headings and small marginal "graffiti") for which the type size and `\baselineskip` are set individually so that struts are unnecessary in these contexts.  the height + depth of the `\strutbox` do equal the `\baselineskip` of 13pt for the main text.  the rationale for these settings is given in knuth's *tugboat* article ["Typesetting Concrete Mathematics"](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf).

regarding whether or not a designer of a plain tex style will follow knuth's lead in setting size-conforming `\strutbox`es, my recommendation is to check the code before making assumptions.  my personal view is that if such `\strutbox`es are not provided, and i were obliged to use that style, i would rewrite the code to provide them.

regarding font metadata in otf, my guess is that it depends on the whim of whoever designed the font metrics. sorry, i can't provide links, but maybe @KhaledHosny (implementor of the `xits` fonts and others) can address this point.