# Is `\hspace*` equivalent to `\strut\hspace`?

Tags: spacing, starred-version

Is using `\hspace*` essentially the same as `\strut\hspace`?

The description at [\hspace vs. \hspace*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89082/1744) seems to suggest that this may be the case, but I was wondering the cases where they might differ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\hspace*` is also valid at the beginning of a line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\hrulefill\sloppy

This is a sentence which makes no sense. 
\hspace{3cm} And so on \ldots

This is a sentence which makes no sense. 
\hspace*{3cm} And so on \ldots

This is a sentence which makes no sense. 
\strut\hspace{3cm} And so on \ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\strut` is only a box with height and depth from `(` and no width! The behaviour of `\hspace*` is similiar to `\vspace*` for the vertical shift.

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks Herbert. I expected `\strut\hspace` would work at the beginning of a line i.e. that the `strut` would make the `hspace` no longer at said beginning of line. :) This is helpful – I was clearly confused about what the strut does. I'm also curious about the case of `\hspace{1em}\strut\hspace{1em}`

Comment: `\strut` is the same as an invisible character/word. With  `\hspace{1em}\strut\hspace{1em}` it is possible to split the the space if `\strut` appears at the beginning of a line, then the second `\hspace{1em}` is used.

Comment: Thanks Herbert. I would not have expected the *visibility* or *width* of the `strut` to determine whether it is considered present/existent from the layout perspective. Unexpected, but not really surprising. 

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt `\strut` does have the effect of stopping hspace being dropped at the beginning of a line, the main difference, as shown in egreg's answer with `\hspace*` is that as a `\strut` has a vertical size it can affect vertical position if it ends up being the largest thing on that line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Herbert's example in this answer seems to show that \strut does not have the effect of stopping \hspace being dropped at the beginning of the line.  Am I misunderstanding in some way?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty if the strut and hspace are on the same line it would stop the space being dropped, so if you start a line that way for example, but as egreg notes there is a break point after the strut so if you have a strut at the end of one line and hspace at start of the next then it is dropped. You could factor that out and use \strut\nobreak\hspace... but then you need a kern to protect against \unskip, and use a zero height strut and basically you've got \hspace* :-)

Comment: Hmm, why are the first two "This is a sentence" lines justified and the last one left-aligned?  (Or simply spaced out less, it's hard to tell.)

Answer (score 5):

No, they're not the same. When you use `\hspace*{1cm}` (or whatever length), LaTeX transforms this into

```
\@hspacer{1cm}
```

which in turn becomes

```
\vrule \@width \z@ \nobreak \hskip #1\hskip \z@skip
```

as described in my answer to the question you linked. The rule is as high and deep as the horizontal box that eventually it is typeset in.

On the contrary, `\strut` does `\unhcopy\strutbox`, that is, it delivers the contents of a box register that also contain a zero width rule, but such that the sum of height and depth equals the (natural size of the) current baseline skip. The box register's contents is updated whenever a font size changing command (such as `\normalsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\large` or even `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont`)  is processed, so the height and depth of `\strut` always (well, almost) reflects the current baseline skip. LaTeX divides the amount in 7 to 3 proportion, so if the baselineskip is 12pt, the height and depth of the strut are 8.4pt and 3.6pt respectively. See [Definition of \strut explained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21832/definition-of-strut-explained) for a subtle point about `\strut`, but it is relevant only if math mode is concerned.

That's the difference: the height and depth of a line where `\hspace*` appears is only influenced by the letters in it, more precisely by the boxes in it; with `\strut\hspace{1cm}` you get height and depth whose sum is at least equal to `1\baselineskip` (it can be bigger if unusually large boxes are contained in the list).

Moreover, `\strut\hspace{1cm}` has a feasible break point between the strut and the glue, which `\hspace*{1cm}` hasn't. Another difference is that `\strut\hspace{1cm}` will disappear at the end of a paragraph (not the strut, but the glue), because TeX does `\unskip` there; on the other hand `\hspace*{1cm}` will not disappear even if `\unskip` is applied, because of the trailing `\hskip\z@skip` glue, so `\unskip` will cancel this and not the main glue.